# Catalina requires a reboot in order to function properly again

Tags: reboot, macos-catalina

After a certain time using my MacBook I get an alert when opening new applications (both native and third-party).

> The Application "Photos" can't be opened

The only option I then have is to reboot my computer, since I can't open activity monitor or attempt to fix the problem in a Terminal.

The Terminal (if already open) then tells me the following:

> forkpty: Resource temporarily unavailable

or

> bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

[image: lots of apps not working]

[image: macOS version]

I am wondering how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: How old is the hardware? Could it be a problem with the harddisk? Heating issue? If this only happens after a while, repeatedly, it doesn't seem like a software problem.

Comment: @SPRBRN: This did only occur _after_ I updated to Catalina. The Hardware is fairly new. I have a MacBook Pro 2017 model with touch bar.

Comment: I'd overlay the OS again from Recovery as a simple first step. It shouldn't affect any existing data - but you of course have a backup anyway, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The reason of this issue was creation of numerous "cron" processes (in my case every 5 minutes) for a Laravel website. After disabling of the cron running Catalina started to work properly.

Comment: I'll give that a shot! It sounds plausible because upping some max-process-setting did already improve the situation. Maybe those cron processes aren't properly cleaned up.